# Two classes in one class in Blue J

Tags: java, class, bluej

I am working on a project on banking. I am using BlueJ as my IDE. Can I use more than one class in the source code.
    `package Bank;
    public class Bank{
    //some methods
    //some code
    }
    class Main{//Calling this class from another .java file.
    //some methods
    public void getRandom()
    {
    return somenumber;
    }
    }`
I cannot call class Main from another class.
Can anyone explain me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two public classes in one file. Your code compiles because `Main` is not public. But that means only the code in `Bank` can see it. To call `Main` from another class, create a file `Main.java` for your `Main` class and move the code into it.

Comment: `Main` isn't a `public` class here, so it is possible to have it into one file. And `Main` not having any modifiers it is `package public`, so still accessible from `Bank`.

I think this is more a problem of a beginner not understanding classes and encapsulation.

Comment: Yes I am a beginner.

Comment: But Why does it not work .I've seen others make it work.

Comment: @ShashidharYBhat is all your code in one file? Inside which class are you trying to use code from Main?

Comment: Yes in BlueJ,In one file

Comment: I am using it from another class in the same package

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the line of code in Bank that you are trying to call something in Main, and also the code in Main?

Comment: The program that i am making is a 100 page project so I cannot Include it.

Comment: You don't need to post it all, just the relevant parts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And which class is calling `getRandom`?

Comment: Another class from the same package

Comment: So the problem is that the other class is in a different file, but the Main class is not public. Did you try moving Main into its own java file and making it public?

Comment: I am not supposed to have multiple classes in my project.

Comment: That is a strange requirement... I would suggest making Main public and Bank package (so move the public modifier from Bank to Main).